# What is "options" in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What is "**options**" in Backbone.js that I see all over the official [source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-2) and also used in a tutorial blog by [Thomas Davis](http://thomasdavis.github.com/2011/02/01/backbone-introduction.html) with sample code here:

```
Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     initialize: function (models, options) {
                   this.bind("add", options.view.addFriendLi); 
                 }
});
```

I don't see any other tutorials using it, and even the doc mentioning it. It does, but in a context kind of format ([options]), not in a hard-coded "options": `options.view.addFriendLi`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`options`, conventionally, is a javascript object of key/value pairs that provide data/context/arguments/configuration to a method call.  Think of it like named arguments, as opposed to ordered arguments.

For example:

```
var makePerson = function(name, options) {
  var person = {};
  person.name = name;
  person.age  = options.age;
  return person;
};

var me = makePerson('Alex', {age:30}); // In 3 days... scary :(
```

How the function being called uses this object, is up to that function.

The documentation for backbone for `Collection.initialize()` does not seem to list what keys on the options object are used or expected, which is unfortunate.  So without looking at the source, there is no way to tell.  But your example does seem to indicate a `view` key is expected.  So you might call it like this:

```
var friendsCollection = new Friends(userModels, {view: someBackboneView});
```

This is simply a convention many libraries tend to use, and there is nothing special about it.    But usually many keys in an object that is passed to a function call is better than a funciton that you call with many arguments, because each value has a label which makes it clear what each value is for.

---

Looking a bit further, now here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-53

It looks like `Collection.initialize()` only accepts a single key in it's options: `comparator`.  Here you can define a function used to sort the models in the collection:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator

Working that into your example, you would call that like this:

```
var friendsCollection = new Friends(userModels, {
  view: someBackboneView,
  comparator: function(friend) {
    return friend.get('age');
  }
});
```

Comment: I like your answer. I definitely learned something from it so +1, but I'm asking it in the context of Backbone.js. It's not [options] that I'm asking but a hard-coded "options" from withing Backbone.js. However, great answer in a different context :)

Comment: Edited with more about how backbone specifically handles options in this method.

Comment: Well that does make sense. Thanks for the time :)

Comment: I think this answer will have to be changed in 2015 :(  this.options is no longer automatically assigned in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can see the tutorial blog by Thomas Davis with sample code, the `Backbone.View.extend` will answer your question:

```
....
AppView=Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$("body"),
    initialize:function(){
        this.friends=new Friends(null, {view:this});
        //Create a friends collection when the view is initialized,
        //Pass it a reference to this view to create a connection between the two
    }
....
```

The key is `this.friends=new Friends(null, {view:this});`

From the above code `initialize:function(models, options)`

So you can know,the "options" == "{view:this}"

It creates a new friends and passes in a parameter ({view:this}), then it passes itself to the above function.

Combine the code `options.view.addFriendLi`,we can know why it can call the method `.addFriendLi`.