# Pass associative array as parameter to make a backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm getting a "SyntaxError: invalid label" error from this code, even without instantiating the model:

*name* is supposed to be a simple string, but *data* is an associative array.

I'm not finding any examples exactly like this - am I misusing backbone?

```
var arrayModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function( name, data ) {
        name: name,
        key: data.AName,
        tech: data.Tech,
        // not really used
        array_type: data.array_type,
        desc: data.desc
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up the syntax for function expressions with the syntax for object literals.

Perhaps you meant:

```
var arrayModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function( name, data ) {
      return {
        name: name,
        key: data.AName,
        tech: data.Tech,
        // not really used
        array_type: data.array_type,
        desc: data.desc
      };
    }
});
```

Or maybe:

```
var arrayModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: (function( name, data ) {
      return function(){
        this.name = name;
        this.key = data.AName;
        this.tech = data.Tech;
        // not really used
        this.array_type = data.array_type;
        this.desc = data.desc;
      };
    })()
});
```

I'm not sure exactly since i'm not familiar with Backbone.js

Comment: it looks like there is something like this.  it looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997714/what-is-options-in-backbone-js backs you up on this.